# In my .htaccess I want to Rewrite the url ONLY in case there is no subdomain in the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like example.com to rewrite to www.example.com but only when there is no subdomain in the url:

```
example.com -> rewrite to www.example.com

s.example.com -> no rewrite

peace.example.com -> no rewite
```

etc..
etc..

All the subdomain rewrites I found add the www regardless of it having a subdomain or not and that is messing me up. I do not want it to redirect to www.c.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two virtual hosts and define for each a different rewrite rule.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
# rewrite to www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName *.example.com
# do not rewrite
</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit:**

This requires the use of virtual host files though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

**Flags:**

- `NE` - No encoding
- `L`  - Last rule
- `R=301` - Redirect with http status=301

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$` will make it execute when domain is `example.com`.

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: Hi @anubhava can explain what this does, because I never seen the [NE] before and what does the [L] do?

Comment: I have wordpress, is it possible that is over ruling the htaccess, because it is still adding the www. to my subdomaines like www.c.example.com

Comment: If it is WP then 1. Make sure this is very first rule below `RewriteEngine On` line. 2) Also make sure your site and home url is set to `www.example.com` in permalinks

Comment: @Theo: May I know if this answer is not working after 6.5 years all of a sudden for you?